# React Native how can I display InterstitialAds in Admob google mobile ads when a user close a page or go back to previous page

Tags: react-native, admob, google-ads-api, google-mobile-ads

How can I implement InterstitialAd ads when a user closes the currently visited page.

A user also can go back(close a page) from a page using his mobile device back button(not react native back header button).

Please check the below code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Button, Text, ScrollView, } from 'react-native';
import { AppOpenAd, InterstitialAd, RewardedAd, BannerAd, TestIds, AdEventType } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
const Test = ({ navigation }) => {
useEffect(() => {
        let interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(TestIds.INTERSTITIAL, {
            requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
            keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
        });
        interstitial.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.LOADED, () => {
            interstitial.show();
        });
        interstitial.load();
        return () => {
            interstitialListener = null;
        };
    }, []);
return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <Text>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
</Text>
                </View>

            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
export default Test
```

My*App.js* file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Test from './Test';
import TestTwo from './TestTwo';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeTabs = ({ navigation }) =>{
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Test" component={Test} />
     </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function App () {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Tab.Screen name="TestTwo" component={TestTwo} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already done this in many apps, so understand and run the below code.

```
   const {showAd, adDismissed, adPresentError, connected,
  setAdShowingInterstitial} = useContext(AppContext);
      const [voicePressed, setVoicePressed] = useState(false);
      useEffect(()=>{
          if(adDismissed || adPresentError || !connected){
              setAdShowingInterstitial(false);
              navigation.navigate('backscreen')// 
          }
      },[adDismissed,adPresentError,connected]);
  //  you have to call adShow function in backbtnPress like below

  function handleBackButtonClick() {
    showAd();
    setInterstitial("backscreen")
    return true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", 
    handleBackButtonClick);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", 
      handleBackButtonClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: may be some code it have missing but logic that.....